# Efficiently assign a color to each character in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to visualize the results of some computational analysis over a large piece of text. The analysis gives me a score [0-100) for each character. I've defined some classes:

```
.c0 { background-color:rgb(6,50,99); }
.c1 { background-color:rgb(7,52,102); }
.c2 { background-color:rgb(8,54,105); }
.c3 { background-color:rgb(10,58,111); }
```

and the bulk of my document looks like this:

`<span class='c76'>i</span><span class='c75'>c</span><span class='c76'>k</span><span class='c73'>l</span><span class='c70'>y</span><span class='c72'>,</span><span class='c76'> </span><span class='c76'>a</span><span class='c78'>n</span><span class='c78'>d</span><span class='c76'> </span><span class='c76'>b</span><span class='c76'>e</span><span class='c76'>`

This works well visually (see blurred screenshot as an example):

[image]

but it is extremely slow to view. For large documents this drags the computer down to a standstill. Is there a more efficient way of rendering this information to a browser, perhaps one that uses JavaScript?

Comment: I'd think using CSS to set colors would be a lot faster than using JavaScript.

Comment: so you mean each character will have a specific color ? so all the `a` same color, all the `b`, etc ?

Comment: How do you determine which characters get which colors? You have several adjacent characters that have the same class/color, but are encased by separate `span`s which seems redundant and may contribute to the performance issue.

Comment: @TemaniAfif not quite, for example the vector `[h,e,l,l,o]` might be encoded as `[37, 37, 30, 32, 36]`, the `l`s are not the same color. What I have is a long list of characters, and a long list of integers that encode a color.

Comment: and what is the login of each color for each number ? maybe we can find a way to avoid having 100 Classe for each color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely consider using the HTML 5 **canvas**. It renders separately from the DOM, usually with some form of acceleration. You should find no slowdown when viewing, though it may still take a second or so for the initial render.

You can do something like this to draw a character with a background:

```
ctx.font = font;
ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
ctx.fillStyle = colour;

var width = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
ctx.fillRect(x-1, y, width+1, parseInt(font, 10));

ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a rough example to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/q2cwxnbp/3/

The drawback to this method is that the text cannot be selected / copied, because it's rendered graphically.

Comment: @Hooked you can maybe use the canvas as background then ;) and keep the text using HTML